# Github how to quality control others upstream new commits

Tags: git, github

New to Git and just started to use Github. Just created my first public repo on there. I know that the public can fork my repo at any time. I also know that others can commit new changes and upstream to my repo on Github.

I wanted to know is there a way to quality control the commits coming through? I wouldn't want random commits from people and want to make sure the code is actually up to quality standards. Is there a way to stop others from committing upstream back to my public repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others can not push to your repo per se unless you explicitly allow them to.

What they can do is fork your code and file so-called *pull requests* – basically asking you to merge their changes into your repo – which you can then approve or decline.

[More on pull requests in the GitHub help section](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful to know I wasn't aware of pull requests.